# Reload a List after Edit a Item in React with a modal box - pass functions from one component to other

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a CRUD table, for that i have created 2 files, one that list the table and the other that edit each item of the list. I am using a modal for editing or creating.

The interaction with the api and database are working fine. But there are two issues that are going on.

1. After clicking in the Button Submit in the file CategoryForm, the modal doesn't close, it still open, don't know how to pass this function from the list to the form. And use it from there.
2. The table does not reload with the new row added with the data inserted.(the data is going correctly to the api and database). Also thinks that need to pass this from the list component to the form and call it from there.

Thanks in advance. I don't know if having two files with two components is the best solution, so i am open to suggestions.

This is the List File, called **Categories.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Alert, Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Datatable from '../../../globalcomponents/datatable/Datatable';
import CategoryForm from './CategoryForm';
import { FaPencilAlt,FaTrashAlt  } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Api = require('../../api/CategoriesApi.js')

class Categories extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null,
      isOpen: false,
      id: null
      }
  }

  openModal = (id) => {
    this.setState( (prev) => {
        const state = prev.state;
        return { ...state, id: id, isOpen:true };
      });
      };
  closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  componentDidMount() {
    Api.getCategories()
      .then(response => {
        const [error, data] = response
        if (error) {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            categories: [],
            error: data
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            categories: data
          })
        }
      })
  } 

  removeCategory = (id) => {
    var categories = [...this.state.categories];
    var index  = categories.findIndex(function(item, i){return item.id === id})
    categories.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({categories});
    Api.deleteCategory(id)
}
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, categories } = this.state

    if (error) {

      return (
        <Alert color="danger">
          Error: {error}
        </Alert>
      )

    } else if (!isLoaded) {

      return (
        <Alert color="primary">
          Loading...
        </Alert>
      )

    } else {

      return (
        <>            
            <Button 
            className="float-right" 
            variant="primary" 
            onClick={e => this.openModal()}
            >
              Adicionar
            </Button>
            
            <h4 className="mt-4 mb-4">Categorias de investimentos</h4>
            <Datatable>
              <table className="table table-striped my-4 w-100">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Url (Slug)</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {categories.map(category => (
                  <tr key={category.id}>
                    <td>{category.id}</td>
                    <td>{category.title}</td>
                    <td>{category.slug}</td>
                    <td>
                      <Button 
                      className="btn btn-danger float-right" 
                      onClick={(event) =>
                         this.removeCategory(category.id)
                      }
                      ><FaTrashAlt /></Button>
                      <Button
                        className="btn btn-success float-right mr-2 "
                        onClick={() =>this.openModal(category.id)}
                      >
                        <FaPencilAlt />
                      </Button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </Datatable>        
            
            <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Adicionar / Editar</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <CategoryForm id={this.state.id || null}/>
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                  Close
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            </>



     )

    }

  }
}

export default Categories
```

and this is the form file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { Row, Col, Alert, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap'

const Api = require('../../api/CategoriesApi.js')

class CategoryForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { 
      category: {
        id: this.getCategoryId(props),
        title: '',
        slug: '',
      },
      redirect: null,
      errors: [],
      reload: false
    }

    this.setTitle = this.setTitle.bind(this)
    this.setSlug = this.setSlug.bind(this)
    
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }


  getCategoryId(props) {
    try {
      return props.id
    } catch (error) {
      return null
    }
  }

  setTitle(event) {
    let newVal = event.target.value || ''
    this.setFieldState('title', newVal)
  }

  setSlug(event) {
    let newVal = event.target.value || ''
    this.setFieldState('slug', newVal)
  }

  setFieldState(field, newVal) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = prevState
      newState.category[field] = newVal
      return newState
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let category = {
      title: this.state.category.title,
      slug: this.state.category.slug,
    }

    Api.saveCategory(category, this.state.category.id)
      .then(response => {
        const [error, errors] = response
        if (error) {
          this.setState({
            errors: errors
          })
        } else {  
          this.setState(
            () => this.setState({reload: true})
          )
        
      
        }
      })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      if (this.props.id ) {
        Api.getCategory(this.props.id).then((response) => {
            const [error, data] = response;
            if (error) {
                this.setState({
                    errors: data
                });
            } else {    
                this.setState({
                    category: data,
                    errors: []
                });
            }
        });
      }
    }

  render() {
    const { redirect, category, errors } = this.state

    if (redirect) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={redirect} />
      )
    } else {

      return (
        <>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              {errors.length > 0 &&
                <div>
                  {errors.map((error, index) =>
                    <Alert color="danger" key={index}>
                      {error}
                    </Alert>
                  )}
                </div>
              }

              <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="title">Title</Label>
                  <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={category.title} placeholder="Enter title" onChange={this.setTitle} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="slug">Slug</Label>
                  <Input type="text" name="slug" id="slug" value={category.slug} placeholder="Enter slug" onChange={this.setSlug} />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button color="success">Submit</Button>
              </Form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default CategoryForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found the way! Add the function, that close modal and update the list in the Categories.jsx, the name was addCategory()

```
class Categories extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null,
      isOpen: false,
      id: null
      }
      this.addCategory = this.addCategory.bind(this);
  }

  addCategory(id, slug, title) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      categories: [{id, slug, title }, ...prevState.categories]
    }));
    this.closeModal()
  }

        <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Adicionar / Editar</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <CategoryForm 
            id={this.state.id || null} 
            addCategory={this.addCategory}
            />
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
```

And in the CategoryForm, create the const for each field props it to the function created in the list, props.addCategory

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let category = {
      title: this.state.category.title,
      slug: this.state.category.slug,
    }

    Api.saveCategory(category, this.state.category.id)
      .then(response => {
        const [error, errors] = response
        if (error) {
          this.setState({
            errors: errors
          })
        } else {  
          this.setState(
          ) 
        }
      })
    const form = event.target;
    const id = " "
    const title = form.elements["title"].value;
    const slug = form.elements["slug"].value;
    this.props.addCategory( id, slug, title);
    form.reset();
      
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In one place you have `const [error, data] = response` in other `const [error, errors] = response`, is it intentional?

You don't pass any cb for close modal or update data to `<CategoryForm id={this.state.id || null}/>`.

`Categories.jsx` component doesn't know when you update data on API.

Maybe something like

```
<CategoryForm id={this.state.id || null} 
    onSubmit={() => {
    closeModal()
    Api.getCategories()
          .then(...
    
    }}/>`
```

Comment: I tried this solution but didn`t work, do i have to pass any cb for close modal or update data to the form as props? In the form there is already a onSubmit function, would that make any conflict? (thanks for the answer)